# How to get started with game programming on the Zune

Tags: xna, zune, xna-3.0

My zune just updated to 3.0 (didn't even realize they were releasing something new!) and the update came with two games, but the Zune marketplace does not have games.

Where do I go to get started, and what are the capabilities of the Zune in terms of games/apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first, you must download the Microsoft XNA 3.0 CTP. Read the documentation, which will explain the capabilities. But, from memory:

- No hardware accelerated 3d (obviously, you can create a software 3d engine and then render the result to a 2d sprite, but... Don't expect much in terms of performance ;))
- No XACT, you must use a new sound API

Answer (score 2):

Just an update but note that XNA 3.0 has been [released](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7d70d6ed-1edd-4852-9883-9a33c0ad8fee&displaylang=en).   It requires some flavor of Visual Studio 2008.

I downloaded it and coded & deployed "hello world" to my Zune in no time at all.  Very easy.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the blog of [Rob Miles](http://www.robmiles.com/xna-book/). He has a few chapters of his book on his site. Great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping someone here would have better resources, but as this seems to be a new area of development, [here's one resource](http://blog.paranoidferret.com/index.php/2008/09/19/zune-game-development-getting-started/) that appears to give all the steps for a newbie to get started (too many assume you already have Visual studio, etc).

I'm really interested in a better in-depth overview of the capabilities as well, though.

-Adam